# WMI Win32_Volume Format Method Returns Access Denied

Tags: c++, com, wmi

I have a C++ application where I am utilizing the format method of the Win32_Volume class.  I have used the following for reference:

[Getting WMI Data from the Local Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Calling a Provider Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

My issue is that the Format method returns with code 3 (access denied) when the application is not ran as admin.  When the application is elevated the return code is 0 (ok).  A user must be able to run my application without elevation.  However, a user does have permission to format a drive through the Windows Format utility, so I am wondering if my COM security settings are correct.

```
//Initialize COM component
hr = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 

//Set general COM security levels
hr =  CoInitializeSecurity(
  NULL,                        // Security descriptor    
  -1,                          // COM negotiates authentication service
  NULL,                        // Authentication services
  NULL,                        // Reserved
  RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication level for proxies
  RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation level for proxies
  NULL,                        // Authentication info
  EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities of the client or server
  NULL);                       // Reserved

IWbemLocator *locator = 0;
//Create connection to WMI namespace
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&locator));

IWbemServices *service = 0;
//Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace (location of WIN32_Volume) with the current user
hr = locator->ConnectServer(BSTR(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 0, &service);

//Set security level on the WMI conection
//Set the proxy so that impersonation of the client occurs.
hr = CoSetProxyBlanket(
  service, 
  RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, 
  RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, 
  NULL, 
  RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, 
  RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, 
  NULL,
  EOAC_NONE);
```

I'm able to retrieve class properties (volume label, file system...) ok no matter what the elevation level is.  It's just the method call itself that returns access denied.  This is all being done on a local machine.  If more code is needed let me know. Thanks!